# will viewpager preload calls api to get the data itself?

Tags: android-viewpager, preload

By default, ViewPager preload one neighbouring page in each direction. So, if next page /fragment will call API to get information or load a picture, does this mean that the page /fragment will automatically call api to do those things?

Answer (score 0):

extends your pagerAdapter with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter` . As documentation: `FragmentPagerAdapter` load all fragment at once and if the fragment load then it's obvious that api's also call.